# Types of Differential Equation Questions

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am self-studying linear algebra right now, and most of the "solve the differential equation" questions I see are somewhat in the form:

$y'' + y' - 6y = 8e^{5x}$

(in terms of y, y'', etc)

I understand these problems and I am usually able to solve them.

However, I came to a question on a practice exam that is not in the same form and I am not exactly sure how to go about solving it.  I am unsure if this is the same type of question, or something entirely different.

Find a particular solution to:

$(\frac{d}{dx} + 1)^3(\frac{d}{dx} - 1) y(x) = -240x^2e^{-x} + 120e^{-x}$

The given solution is:
$2x^5e^{-x} + 5x^4e^{-x}$

If someone could provide an explanation/walkthrough for this differential equation that would be incredibly helpful, so I can learn how to tackle similar problems of the same form in the future. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Attempt at solution:

We have

$(r+1)^3(r-1)$

Which means we have the values -1 with a multiplicity of 3 and also the value 1.

This is the general solution I came up with, unsure of how to reach a particular solution.

$c_1e^t + c_2e^{-t} + c_3te^{-t} + c_4t^2e^{-t}$

Comment: $(D+1)^3 (D-1) y$ can be written as (just multiply the operator out) $$y'''' + 2 y''' -2 y'' - y = -240 x^2 e^{-x}+ 120 e^{- x}$$

Comment: ahh I see, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: The first step would be to not multiply them out, since they have given you the factorization of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Peyton Thanks for the tip! I added in my attempt at a general solution, which I believe is correct.  Not quite sure how to get the particular solution, though.

Comment: How do you usually solve $y''+y'-6y=8e^{5x}$? Undetermined Coefficients, Variation of Parameters, Laplace Transforms?

Comment: There are lots of ways to get a solution for this type of equations: Variation of the constants, integral transforms. Since the independent term is a "quasi polynomial" there is a way to predict the form of a solution such that you can find it by indeterminate coefficients. I would check a book in ordinary differential equations. My first pick is Arnold's.

Comment: @Moo I think you mean: $$y''''+2y'''-\color{red}{2y'}-y=-240x^2 e^{-x}+120e^{-x}$$

Comment: @projectilemotion: Correct - I typed it wrong - good catch!